# How could everything happens is for good only?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, identification-request

> Whatever has happened has happened for the good. What is happening is also happening for the good. Whatever will happen will be for good also.

Reading the above translated text may be taken from Gita (I am not sure, but I gave reference link below) is quite understandable. But I want to know how did lord Krishna explain this "All for the good theory" which satisfy for each and every kind of individual?

Shall we consider it happened for the good if someone intentionally kills someoneone with out any reason?

Edit : [reference](http://www.eaglespace.com/spirit/geetaenglish.php)

Comment: What Gita verse are you referring to?

Comment: There are lots of small text as well as picture messages in blogs and in various sites which says so and so is according to gita. Don't usually trust those quotes unless chapter & verse no. are mentioned below. I think someone raised this issue and even asked a question regarding this.

Comment: You may self close this Qn with: [Which famous quotes are wrongly attributed to Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23751/1049)

Answer (score 3):

> *"Whatever has happened ... is happening ... will happen ... for good."*

Bhagavad Gita doesn't have such verse present in it.