# Which famous quotes are wrongly attributed to Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, identification-request

There are many famous sayings, found in Facebook, WhatsApp & other social media, which are wrongly linked to Bhagavad Gita.

Purpose of this Qn is to link all the duplicates in one place.

<sub>Meta discussion: [A question related to "Wrong attribution to Bhagavad Gita", should be kept open](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152/1049)</sub>

Comment: Don't u think that smitcreation.com should be cropped out?

Comment: I mean, in the pics u posted, there is a name of website which has created these pictures. I think that should me cropped or ignore if it's not a prbm

Comment: @Secret, got it now. Actually the "verses" in the answers were anyways famous even before the website. In recent years, such websites & through other media, these "verses" were glorified using images. For example a famous images website pinterest.com also contains such pseudo verses. These websites may contain correct & incorrect both kind of quotes. They simply picturise any famous quote. Hence no point in banning them. :-)

Comment: It's better if you make one "wiki" answer without pics. Also, list questions are generally off-topic  and it also looks like " too broad". See [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334)

Comment: It *is* too broad, no doubt, Stack Exchange isn't a place for a "list of things", like posts. However, this post is certainly quite useful both as a duplicate target and as a place to know the truth. @TheDestroyer, is there any reason why the post can't be made a wiki-lock? Anyway, the OP have themselves made their answers CW, hence as a moderator, you would not be using the wiki lock as a rep denial tool. (This post does look like a good candidate for such a lock)

Comment: @TheDestroyer, I am fine to combine all wiki answers in 1, but that would be too long as and when we keep adding new answers. Since for this particular topic, the Qn-s keep popping up, we may take exception in this & similar topics. Yet, we can discuss more in chat room if required to have a consensus.

Comment: @iammilind discuss this on meta.

Comment: @Rohith. he already has posted a question.

Comment: "Purpose of this wiki question..." Do you want to make the question a community wiki? Btw, linking all the question at one place sounds useful, however closing all the questions as dupe may not be a good idea.

Comment: @Pandya, initially I was ok for full wiki. But then in the special case when answer requires extra explanation (verse is partially true), we may still require a separate answer. Which shoukd not be a community wiki & is worth reputation for efforts.

Answer (score 8):

This wiki answer contains those legacy posts, which are answered somewhere else.

---

> If you don't fight for what you want then don't cry for what you lost.

More details are found in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15407/1049).

---

By Anthony De Mello:

> ...Lord Krishna says to Arjuna: "Plunge into the heat of battle and keep your heart at the lotus feet of the Lord".

More details are found in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24610/1049).

---

Generally found in popular culture:
[Does Gita states that "... Atmaa discards old bodies and assumes new bodies"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29043)

---

Answer (score 7):

This wiki answer contains, those quotes, which are straightforward not related to Gita.

---

> Whatever has happened has happened for the good. What is happening is also happening for the good. Whatever will happen will be for good also.

---

> What did you lose that you cry about? What did you bring with you, which you think you have lost? What did you produce, which you think got destroyed? You did not bring anything, whatever you have, you received from here. Whatever you have given, you have given only here. Whatever you took, you took from God. Whatever you gave, you gave to Him. You came empty handed, you will leave empty handed.

---

> The world isn't bad because of bad people's deed. It's bad because inaction of good people.

There was in fact a similar/inspired dialogue in a Hindi movie [Singh Saab the Great](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singh_Saab_the_Great). See [this video](https://youtu.be/aPagatp4poU?t=01m21s).

---

> In gita Krishna explicitly literally said that: "anyone believing in him should believe that Bhagwad Gita is Lord Krishna Himself"

---

Answer (score 6):

> You perform action, don't worry about the result.

This is a fuzzy verse, which looks similar but has a different meaning. There is no such word as "worry"; the correct term is "right" (*adhikAra*).

> कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन। मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि
>   BG 2.47 - You have right only on actions; Never on [its] results; Let not be [an agent] for results of actions; Let not be attached to inaction.