# Is this citation of Anthony De Mello correct?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

In the book "[Awareness](http://demellospirituality.com/awareness/the-four-steps-to-wisdom.html)" of Anthony De Mello I've read the following quotation "from the sacred book of the Hindus":

> ...Lord Krishna says to Arjuna: "Plunge into the heat of battle and keep your heart at the lotus feet of the Lord".

But I can not find such place in the Bhagavadgita. Some of my acquaintance researchers in private conversation told me that this is probably wrong citation based on BhG 3.30.

My question: is it correct citation or not?

P.S. I haven't found this citation in this question: [Which famous quotes are wrongly attributed to Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/which-famous-quotes-are-wrongly-attributed-to-bhagavad-gita)

I am curious: if it is wrong, what's the basis of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which famous quotes are wrongly attributed to Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/which-famous-quotes-are-wrongly-attributed-to-bhagavad-gita)

Comment: It is a decent enough interpretation of nishkama karma yoga.

Comment: @iammilind I haven't found this citation in that possible-duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

**No, quoted text is not found in Bhagavad Gita.**

BG 3.30 and BG 8.7 are the closest verses:

> BG 3.30 - Devoid of the fever of the soul, **engage in battle by dedicating all actions to Me**, with (your) mind intent on the Self, and becoming free from expectations and egoism.
>   BG 8.7 - **Therefore, think of Me at all times and fight.** There is no doubt that by dedicating your mind and intellect to Me, you will attain Me alone.

---

<sub>We ideally should merge this answer here: [Which famous quotes are wrongly attributed to Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/which-famous-quotes-are-wrongly-attributed-to-bhagavad-gita)</sub>

Comment: Yes ,Saw  that , i was just pointing you towards adding original sanskrit /english shlokas in the answer.