# 'Whatever happens, happens for good, is this verse found In any scriptures?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, identification-request

Many of us have heard this even in Hindi

> Jo hota hain acha ke liye hota hain.

Is this concept found in any scriptures of Hinduism? Is this really part of Hindu philosophy or not? Is it shown anywhere in Ramayana or Mahabharata?

Comment: There is a verse saying - **जगदम्बापदस्मर्तुः सङ्कटं न कदाचन । यदि जायते तच्चापि ज्ञेयं तत्स्वस्तये किल ॥** "**Who remembers the feet of Mother of Universe, afflictions never ever befall on him. Even if it happens, it is to be known that it will turn out for his welfare.**

Comment: Related quote discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23753/277)

Comment: May be influenced by होइहि सोइ जो राम रचि राखा। को करि तर्क बढ़ावै साखा॥

Comment: It is often cited as "the essence of gita"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which famous quotes are wrongly attributed to Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/which-famous-quotes-are-wrongly-attributed-to-bhagavad-gita). This verse is not found anywhere and is typically linked with Bhagavad Gita. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23753/1049).

Comment: @iammilind it's not a Duplicate. I didt ask refernce only from Bhagavd Gita,from other scriptures too where this kind of Verse may found or maybe in ramyana or mahabharata.

Comment: Is the concept found in any scriptures? is the Q.. So just the scripture tag is enough ..since nothing specific in the Q about Bg or Upanishads i have removed them ..@KarmanyaNanda

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda If you want the souce of the verse, just use the identification request tag. The tag wiki is clear. That is enough. If the question is about a scripture, use it. You have done a good job on selecting some of the tags but scripture is not needed to the question since you are not asking about a scripture but a reference. You can remove it.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/904/5212) from Pandya which is received well by the community and  also the recent discussion which took place recently about [tagging with scripture](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1191/5212). If the OP is unsure about the source of the verse or story, we should just add Identification request tag. Adding the tag when the question has nothing to do with scriptures is redundant. There are already relevant tags. We as a site should bit be partial towards a single tag.  @KarmanyaNanda You can just remove the tag. .

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ok,Done!

Comment: For this Q in particular the scripture is ok to add... @KarmanyaNanda From Pandya's answer on Meta "Out of 3 questions you mentioned, last two don't deserve scripture tag." so the first one deserve it.. & ur Q here falls under that category..scripture is the most important thing in Hinduism.. so it works well with most post if not all.. this identification request is a useless tag.. If we were to use it then from most Qs asking "What is the story of..? mythology tag should be removed and identification request should be added instead.. read Tezz's answer there too on mEta.

Comment: @Rickross ok I readded it.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda No need to add or remove if me or any other users say so.. see the last line of Pandya's answer :"So, scripture should only be used **if the question is explicitly looking for scriptural base**. In this case u are indeed looking for scriptural basis.. so it's a valid tag to use..

Comment: What is the need of the tag when you already said that you want scriptural reference clearly in the title and body? Not once but twice? Pandya's answer on that post is authority there and agreed. But for Tezz's answer, there are many wrongs. I have pointed out them in the comments. Read the comments under his answer. ID tag is not a useless one. Scriptures are important for Hinduism religion. but scripture tag is not important for hinduism.se . Not using that tag doesn't mean we don't respect them.

Comment: Guys I don't have any knowledge about Suitable Tags,I am confused Regaridng this,If you feel my Tags are not in proper  you Guys can correct it.

Comment: This is the correct tag to use for this Q.. since you are asking for scriptural basis of something.. see the last line of Pandya's answer which i have quoted already.. Some people want to kill the scripture tag here... Hinduism revolves around scripture and they want to kill it!.. Do not worry about tagging ..someone of us will correct tagging if u are wrong.. @KarmanyaNanda

Answer (score 2):

> Indeed, *prakṛti* is equilibrium of the *guṇas*;
>   They are *guṇas* of *prakṛti*, not of *ātman*.
>   Known as *sattva*, *rajas*, and *tamas*,
>   Respectively, they cause *sthiti*, *utpatty*, and *anta*.

—Bhāgavata Purāṇa: Canto XI, Ch 12, Verse 12 (personal partial translation)

Full translation:

> Undeniably, that which is material is a result of equilibrium among the Three Modes;
>   These are modes of the material, not of the spiritual.
>   Known as goodness-harmony, passion-dynamism, and ignorance-cacophony,
>   Respectively, they cause Cosmic Maintenance, Cosmic Generation, and Cosmic Annihilation.

Since maintenance of the material stems from goodness, the nature of the manifest world must be good, even if it seems in our judgement to be bad. Further, when ignorance leads to destruction, another generation event follows. Thereafter further maintenance is required.

For example, if a cow dies in the wilderness a kind of destruction has occurred. The corpse then decays and brings about the total annihilation of its form. This action of decay provides new life for bacteria, fungi, plants, larvae, scavengers, etc.

So, we can say that, while perhaps not all events are *sattvam*, *sattva* is the standard to which *rajas* and *tamas* must lead. For it is in *sattva* that things last. This is why we also call it harmony. *Sattva* is also translated as being-ness, is-ness, or the essence of existence. That which *is not*, has no *sattva*. Thus, everything which occurs, must have goodness as its nature. It is our ignorance which makes us perceive goodness as displeasing.

Evolution has made it easier for us to look for immediate rewards or pleasures and so we call these "good." Like children, we often forget that immediate discomfort may lead to better long-term results. This is why we fail to recognize the intrinsic  goodness in all existing things.

---

Sorry I could not provide you with a more authoritative answer. Hopefully the logic I presented will suffice.

Please do correct any misspellings or diacritic mistakes I have made.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should include this in the answer or not, but it is broadly recognized in Sanatana Dharma that we discriminate between "good" and "bad" because of the useful illusion, *maya*.

Answer (score -1):

**No**, this verse is not likely to be found in traditional scriptures.
Because, it doesn't have any Sanskrit basis.
The Hindi line is usually wrongly attributed to "essence of Bhagavad Gita". Refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/which-famous-quotes-are-wrongly-attributed-to-bhagavad-gita/23753#23753).