# Reference for a colloquial saying in Bhagwad Gita

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

There is an oft quoted statement ,attributed to Lord Krishna in the Bhagavad Gita,that is famous throughout my mother tongue speakers,.

(Below is a translation:)

> The cause(/goal) is what justifies the means(taken to attain that goal).

Can someone give the reference to this verse in the Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: There is no such verse.

Comment: @Pradip Gangopadhyay Oh.That came as a surprise.The statement is often attributed to Lord Krishna(being spoken in the Gita).Anyhow,good to know that it’s a misconception.

Comment: not from Gita...

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/which-famous-quotes-are-wrongly-attributed-to-bhagavad-gita) is a related question which is however now closed. @Amethyst